# Trouble conceiving website administration model

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, admin

I cannot find any material through my research to address a model, they are all implementations - I am asking this question to understand, not to blindly use someone else's CMS or what have you.

**I am trying to** develop an administration model for my PHP website to safeguard typical administration functions and automatic database update scripts (running once a day), but the ideas I have so far have no evidence, I have found, for or against them. I'd rather ask you guys than risk it - so please don't punish.

**Example structure:**

```
/htdocs
    -- index.php
    -- /templates
        -- about.php

/php-files
    -- auth.php
```

**Currently:**

- User authentication handled via an API that returns a (guaranteed) unique ID, which is then bcrypt'd and stored in a Redis key-value database via auth.php

### Elaboration

The problem I have is conceiving a way to uniquely identify an administrator without publicly revealing my administration portal `admin.domain` or `domain/admin` etc....

Assuming the above would the following model securely achieve this?

- Redis key-value contains authenticated users, with their unique ID.
- Progress database contains single relation with attributes: `ID`, `admin`.
- Upon visiting `admin.domain` or `domain/admin` etc... the user is authenticated as usual with Redis, if that fails a 404 is served and handled with .htaccess to look like any old 404 error.
- If previous is successful, unique ID stored in Redis checked against Postgress `ID` attribute `admin`, if `admin = true` then the user is an administrator and `admin.php` can include the admin control panel for display, no further login.

Would this portal, secured as mentioned above, be a secure place to contain scripts automatically updating an entire database or is there a way to execute them above the document root without any intervention below the document root?

Comment: Why do you want to hide the administration portal? I mean you could place it on a uniquely named subdomain; and then use the procedure you described in your post. The 404 error is a nice touch, however because normally with 'non-existent' domain name, you'd get `server not found`, it would only work where you used a directory for the admin panel rather than a subdomain. As for the login, why not just update your login, where it checks whether you are admin, and if you are it redirects you to the admin panel.T here isn't a reason to be paranoid about your admin panel, if your site is secure